# Google Finance Error on 1st Jan Calculation

Tags: google-finance

Why is this formula returning N/A ?
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("bsx","price",date(2018,1,1)))

Yet it works fine for =INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("bsx","price",date(2018,1,2)))

Comment: Holiday, maybe?

Comment: @PaulT. ok. so can I get the last price (i.e ignore a holiday). The same issue doesnt happen for a saturday or a sunday